# Weird file in /tmp

Tags: 20.04

I ran on a weird file in the /tmp of my Ubuntu 20.04 box:

```
-rw------- 1 root     root       26 Okt 10 16:44 yAUhIcBsOý
```

and it contains

```
/var/ffffff/users/superman
```

Neither the user superman nor the dir in /var exists.

There is a second file with same rights, different name and same content in /tmp 3 days earlier.

And I couldn't find s.th. similar in a search.

Any idea?

Comment: Hmm...interesting. I found this: http://osgeeks.net/shell.php?f=/var/c19/.cpan/build///Encode-3.11-0/t/Unicode_trailing_nul.t (text file, harmless AFAICT)

Comment: I believe the program tests the Perl installation on your system for a specific bug. An invalid encoded string is decoded and the result is written to a temporary file. When read back, if it's equal to the first string, the test reports `UTF-16 decodes with trailing NUL`. Question is: who did that testing, and when? With root privileges, no less.

Comment: Thanks for pointing on perl. When updating the software on this box I run a script that has the following line in it: sudo cpan-outdated -p | sudo cpan
The timestamp of the weird file may fit to running this update script.

Comment: I can confirm that running the ```sudo cpan``` commands creates the file in //tmp, but inly when a distribution is updated by the program.